# kvm forward port from Host to guest VM bridge mode

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, port, forwarding

I have a server Ubuntu 22.04 on cloud (VPS) with one external IP (public) address (19.162.31.26), and the internal IP (private) address (192.168.122.1). On that server I use libvirt (Virtual Machine Manager) to run virtual machines (ubuntu16) in bridge mode with IP address (192.168.122.48). see the Figure-1

Now I have installed on VM (ubuntu16) Odoo server and I can access to it via (http:// 192.168.122.48:8069). I want to access at this virtual machine (server -ubuntu16) on my host via http (port 8069) from the outside, using public (http:// 19.162.31.26:8069)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvjq4.png)